# Java waking blocking thread periodically

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program in which there are several threads writing  into a buffer and there is one thread that reads from the buffer and writes into a file.
The buffer is implemented in such a way that an attempt to extract an entry when the buffer is empty causing the thread to block (wait() is used).
The thread uses BufferedStream to write into file.
Currently I am flushing BufferedStream after each 10 times the file is written to.

```
while (true)
{
     BufferEntry entry = buffer.getEntry(); // might block

     logFile.printf("%s", entry);

     ++entriesWritten;

     if (entriesWritten >= 10)
     {
         logFile.flush();
         entriesWritten = 0;
     }
}
```

However, I would like to cover a use case in which after writing x entries (x<10), the buffer remains empty for a long time.
I would like the entries remaining at the buffer for longer than a certain amount of time to be written to the file.

I was thinking about a daemon that wakes periodically to handle flushing, but such daemon will mean that more than one thread will handle a file, which is undesirable. Not to mention that the daemon will have to know when the current unflushed entries were written...

I was thinking about using interrupt method and catching InterruptedException. But I fear this approach is not pretty, besides - interrupt received when writing to file might result in different kind of exception which will need handling.

I am also entertaining an idea to overload Buffer constructor to receive an additional parameter which will make buffer wait for specified amount of minutes instead of forever. Upon awaking it will be possible to check whether flush is needed. My concerns with this solutions is burdening Buffer with something that shouldn't be its concern and also the fact that wait doesn't return an indication regards the reason it unblocks.

Is there a pretty way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

This class offers the functionality of the Object monitor-methods (`wait`, `notify` and `notifyAll`) - they are called `await`, `signal` and `signalAll` in order to avoid the name clash with the methods inherited from `Object`.

What you might be interested in is the method [awaitNanos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#awaitNanos-long-), as it allows you to specify a timeout:

> Causes the current thread to wait until it is signalled or interrupted, or the specified waiting time elapses.

On the other hand, perhaps a simple [`Object.wait(long timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) might be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: I like the suggestion to use Lock and Condition. Condition's method await returns a boolean that indicates whether the thread woke up due to timeout. Together with Alexei's suggestion to overload getEntry to receive timeout it might be a nice to way to solve the problem while still keeping Buffer object general enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said `buffer.getEntry()` calls `Object.wait()`. Implement another method, `buffer.getEntry(long timeout)` which calls `Object.wait(timeout)` and returns null if timeout occurred.

```
     BufferEntry entry = buffer.getEntry(timeout); // might block

     if (entry != null) {
         logFile.printf("%s", entry);
         ++entriesWritten;
     }

     if (entriesWritten >= 10 || entry == null) {
         logFile.flush();
         entriesWritten = 0;
     }
```

Comment: I like your idea to overload getEntry method. This way Buffer just offers an addition service and remains generic enough. At the API docs I don't see Object's wait method having an indication that the thread is awakened due to timeout. I think Hulk's suggestion to use Lock and Condition, together with you suggestion to overload the method will make a nice solution. Thanks